# How to bind to all addresses of only one network interface (Linux)?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, tcp, sockets

What I am trying to achieve is binding an IPv6 socket to any address *of just one particular device*, not system-wide. My intuition is that I could `setsockopt()` with `SO_BINDTODEVICE` followed by a bind to `::`. It *mostly* does what I expect it to do. The behaviour is the same in v4.

The sockets bound to an interface with `SO_BINDTODEVICE` will only accept connections made to addresses on that interface. That much is expected.

However, I run into errno "Address already in use", if I'm trying to bind to a source port on interface B when there is a socket using the same port *but* on interface A.

Ex:

- nic A has IPv6  fd00:aaaa::a/64
- nic B has IPv6  fd00:bbbb::b/64
- they do not share networks.

**Put shortly (pseudocode):**

- process 1 calls `socket(...)` and binds `bind(fd00:aaaa::a/64, 9000)`.
- process 2 calls `socket(...)` and `setsockopt(SO_BINDTODEVICE, "B")`
- process 2 (continued) calls `bind(::, 9000)` and gets `EADDRINUSE`. Why?

How does `SO_BINDTODEVICE` really work? Does the determination for "addresses in use" ignore, conservatively, the interface sockets are bound to? Is it a networking stack layering issue?

**Example traces:**

1. I start a listening socket (server) on a specific address: `nc -l fd00:aaaa::a 9000`. Its trace is as follows:

```c
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(3, {
    sa_family=AF_INET6,
    sin6_port=htons(9000),
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fd00:aaaa::a", &sin6_addr),
    sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0
}, 28) = 0
listen(3, 1)                            = 0
accept(3, ...
```

2. Connecting to it (client) fails if I bind to the port in use by the other interface, even though I've already bound to a different interface:

```c
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "nicB\0", 5) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6,
         sin6_port=htons(9000),
         inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::", &sin6_addr), 
         sin6_flowinfo=0,
         sin6_scope_id=0
        }, 28) = -1 //EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
```

3. However, if I don't specify the port, then all is good when binding to `::` (while the listener still runs):

```c
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "nicB\0", 5) = 0
bind(3, {
    sa_family=AF_INET6,
    sin6_port=htons(0),
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::", &sin6_addr),
    sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0
}, 28) = 0
connect(3, {
    sa_family=AF_INET6,
    sin6_port=htons(9000),
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fd00:aaaa::a", &sin6_addr),
    sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0
}, 28) = ...
```

*Note: This is on 3.19.0-68-generic x86_64 . Ubuntu 14.04. In case it makes a difference, for my tests, nicB is a macvlan in bridge mode whose parent is nicA.*

Comment: IIRC dnsmasq’s DHCP part accomplishes this by somehow detecting where packages are incoming from and then discarding them. You might want to look at its source code.

Comment: I did hesitate when posting here. It could also go to the UNIX and Linux stackexchange site, as this is probably linux specific.
I felt that administrators/superusers might provide guidance -- there is an aspect of trying to control where servers listen for connections in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a satisfying explanation for this problem.

The observation is that even though only interface "A" has IP `fd00:aaaa::a/64` when the program is started, the listening socket could accept connections coming in over different interfaces if they were to receive that IP in the future. IPs can be added and removed -- and server processes listening on `::` or (`0.0.0.0` in v4) need not be restarted when interfaces receive new IPs.

So, in a way, process 1's `bind("fd00:aaaa::a/64", 9000)` binds implicitly to *ALL* interfaces. Even though process 2 only needs to use interface B, process 1's already got first dibs, because it uses port 9000 on *both* interfaces, so process 2 gets denied.

If I change program 1 so that it too uses `SO_BINDTODEVICE` (to interface "A"), then both processes can `bind(::, 9000)` without issues.

**experiment**

I've tested this out with a little LD_PRELOAD goop, which precedes calls to `bind()` with `setsockopt(...SO_BINDTODEVICE...)`. The two following TCP listeners can both bind to port 9000 simulateneously if they are each bound to a different interface.

```
# LD_PRELOAD=./bind_hook.so _BINDTODEVICE=eth0 nc -l 0.0.0.0 9000

# LD_PRELOAD=./bind_hook.so _BINDTODEVICE=eth1 nc -l 0.0.0.0 9000
```

If only one of the two uses `SO_BINDTODEVICE`, then the last process gets `EADDRINUSE`. Which is the situation put forward in the question.

I'm including the C code (GNU/Linux) for my tool in case someone needs something similar:

```
/**                                                                                                                                                              
 * bind_hook.c                                                                                                                                                   
 *                                                                                                                                                               
 * Calls setsockopt() with #SO_BINDTODEVICE before _any_ bind().                                                                                                       
 * The name of the interface to bind to is obtained from                                                                                                         
 * environment variable `_BINDTODEVICE`.
 *
 * Needs root perms. errors are not signalled out.
 *                                                                                                                                                               
 * Compile with:
 *   gcc -Wall -Werror -shared -fPIC -o bind_hook.so -D_GNU_SOURCE bind_hook.c -ldl
 * Example usage:
 *   LD_PRELOAD=./bind_hook.so _BINDTODEVICE=eth0 nc -l 0.0.0.0 9500
 *                                                                                                                                                               
 * @author: init-js
 **/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <errno.h>


static char iface[IF_NAMESIZE];
static int (*bind_original)(int, const struct sockaddr*, socklen_t addrlen);

int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr,
         socklen_t addrlen);

__attribute__((constructor))
void ctor() {
        bind_original = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "bind");

        char *env_iface = getenv("_BINDTODEVICE");
        if (env_iface) {
                strncpy(iface, env_iface, IF_NAMESIZE - 1);
        }
}

/* modified bind() -- call setsockopt first */
int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen) {
        int _errno;

        if (iface[0]) {
                /* preserve errno */
                _errno = errno;
                setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE,
                           (void*)iface, IF_NAMESIZE);
                errno = _errno;
        }
        return bind_original(sockfd, addr, addrlen);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a socket already bound to a specific IP address and port, you can only bind to that port again if you provide another specific IP address. You cannot use INADDR_ANY in this circumstance.

Comment: you can bind two programs to INADDR_ANY (and same port) simultaneously if _both_ binding applications use SO_BINDTODEVICE on different interfaces.